# posting images using library returns nothing

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I am using matt harris' twitter library https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth and following the image upload example.

I get a zero returned when trying to post an image with no $tmhOAuth->response['response'] being returned.

**Steps i have tried**

1. Running the example as it is- fails
2. Running verify ssl- works fine
3. Running the status update with out the image- it posts correctly as expected
4. swapping the url from 1 to 1.1- nothing changes, library still returns zero

It runs quite quickly implying its not even trying to post an image.

Any ideas on why this isnt working or anything i need to configure on the server

Below is the code i copied from the example to try with.

```
<?php
// testing hmac works- correctly
echo hash_hmac('ripemd160', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', 'secret');


$tmhOAuth = array( 'consumer_key' => 'removed',
                   'consumer_secret' => 'removed',
                   'user_token' => 'removed', 
                   'user_secret' => 'removed');


// array(
//   'consumer_key'    => 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY',
//   'consumer_secret' => 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET',
//   'user_token'      => 'A_USER_TOKEN',
//   'user_secret'     => 'A_USER_SECRET',
// )

require 'tmhOAuth.php';
require 'tmhUtilities.php';
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth($tmhOAuth);

// we're using a hardcoded image path here. You can easily replace this with
// an uploaded image - see images.php in the examples folder for how to do this
// 'image = "@{$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']};type={$_FILES['image']['type']};filename={$_FILES['image']['name']}",

// this is the jpeg file to upload. It should be in the same directory as this file.
$image = 'image.png';

$code = $tmhOAuth->request(
  'POST',
  'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
  array(
    'media[]'  => "@{$image};type=image/jpeg;filename={$image}",
    'status'   => 'Picture time',
  ),
  true, // use auth
  true  // multipart
);

if ($code == 200) {
  tmhUtilities::pr(json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']));
} else {
  tmhUtilities::pr($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621133/update-with-photo-in-twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post url https://upload.twitter.com in the request should be http://api.twitter.com